# Add Notification Badge for unread Notifications in Android

Tags: android, notifications, badge

I want to add the count of unread notification at my app icon
I tried this [link](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) but this was not helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Take a look this might work and can make your Android App showing the count of unread messages as a badge on your App shortcut 
>   [shorcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

Comment: But this is in Android studio can you please give me the Ecipse link